# Python script to find employees who are in one PostgreSQL table but not in another

Tags: python, performance, postgresql, join

I'm writing a python script and do database query to get the ids of employees who are in one table but are not in another. I'm using psycopg2  module for python 2 and PostgreSQL as database. After querying from one table based on a condition, I do another query on another table to get the difference between these tables using the result of previous query. The problem is the full procedure takes a long time. I want to know is there any other method or technique which can make the entire procedure faster?
Below is the code I used for doing my feature:

```
def find_difference_assignment_pls_count(self):
        counter = 0
        emp_ids = []
        self.test_cursor.execute("""Select id,emp_id from test_test where flag=true and emp_id is not null and ver_id in(select id from test_phases where state='test')""")
        matching_records = self.test_cursor.fetchall()

        for match_record in matching_records:
            self.test_cursor.execute("""Select id from test_table where test_emp_id=%s and state='test_state'""",(match_record['emp_id'],))
            result = self.test_cursor.fetchall()

            if result:
                continue
            else:
                emp_ids.append(match_record['emp_id'])
                counter +=1

        print "Employees of test_test not in test_table: ", counter
        return emp_ids
```

I run these queries on two tables which at least have more than 500000 records. Therefore the performance is really slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LEFT JOIN](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-left-join/) from `test_test` to `test_table` selecting only rows where `test_table.test_emp_id` is `null`.

```
select emp_id 
from test_test
left join test_table on (
    test_table.test_emp_id = test_test.emp_id and
    test_table.state = 'test_state'
)
where (
    test_test.flag = true and 
    test_test.emp_id is not null and
    test_test.ver_id in (
        select id
        from test_phases
        where state = 'test'
    ) and
    test_table.test_emp_id is null
)
```

You may also want to consider:

1. Using an inner join instead of a subquery to select only rows with `test_phases.state = 'test'`.
2. Selecting `distinct` `emp_id`s if `test_test.emp_id` does not have a unique constraint.

```
select distinct emp_id 
from test_test
inner join test_phases on test_phases.id = test_test.ver_id
left join test_table on (
    test_table.test_emp_id = test_test.emp_id and
    test_table.state = 'test_state'
)
where (
    test_test.flag = true and 
    test_test.emp_id is not null and
    test_phases.state = 'test' and
    test_table.test_emp_id is null
)
```